# Fields as array when I select in elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch in my system and I have a question.

When I use GET in this uri:

```
/dev/category/_search
```

I receive this:

```
{
...
"title": "Sound",
"slug": "sound",
...
}
```

It's correct. But I have many fields in this query and I want to optimize this one.

I GET this uri:

```
/category/_search?show_in_menu=true&fields=title,slug
```

When I add the param fields, all fields are returning as array. In this example, return this:

```
"fields": {
           "slug": [
               "Sound"
           ],
           "title": [
               "sound"
           ]
       }
```

There is a way to return only the field intead of an array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

> Allows to control how the _source field is returned with every hit.

Example from documentation:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "include": [ "obj1.*", "obj2.*" ],
        "exclude": [ "*.description" ],
    }
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.